# List of eigenvalues of a list of abstract states

Tags: list-manipulation, physics, eigenvalues

Suppose I have the states `\Psi`, `\Phi` and `\Zeta` and I also have the following relations given by the operators `A` and `B` when acting in the states

```
A.\Psi=1*\Psi;
B.\Psi=2*\Psi;
A.\Phi=3*\Phi;
B.\Phi=4*\Phi;
A.\Zeta=3*\Zeta;
B.\Zeta=4*\Zeta;
```

where I am denoting by a `dot` the action of `A` and `B`. If I define

```
list1={A,B};
list2={10*\Psi,5\Phi + \Zeta};
```

And, from them, I multiply the two lists

```
list3=Table[Table[i.j,{i,list1}],{j,list2}]
```

giving

```
list3={{A.10*\Psi,B.10*\Psi},{A.(5\Phi + \Zeta),B.(5\Phi + \Zeta)}}
     ={{1*(10*\Psi),2*(10*\Psi)},{3*(5\Phi + \Zeta),4*(5\Phi + \Zeta)}}
```

where the second line comes after using the relations given in the first lines of code.

How do I make Mathematica write only the eigenvalues of the operators A and B when acting on list2 (I want it to write {{1,2},{3,4}} from list3)?

Comment: Can you please explain why ``5\Phi + \Phi`` is not equal to ``6\Phi``? Also, I'm having troubles understanding the task ... Are you looking for something like: ``a[psi] = 1;
b[psi] = 2;
a[phi] = 3;
b[phi] = 4;
Table[f[First@Variables@j], {f, {a, b}}, {j, {10 psi, 6 phi}}]``?

Comment: @Domen Sorry, It was a mistake and now I edited.

Comment: are you sure in advance that all the states in ``list2`` are eigenstates? What should be the result of the code if it is not an eigenstate, for example, ``A[Ψ + Φ]``?

Comment: @Domen Yes, all states in list2 are eigenstates of the operators in list1 in my case

Comment: In that case, the code from my comment above should work. Have you tried it? Given your definitions of the operators, the prefactors you are looking for can be simply determined by the combination of the operator and the state.

Comment: @Domen Yes, I was implementing in my code. It worked, thanks

Comment: OP, can you, please, put your working code as a self-answer with appropriate credit & accept your self-answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Domen wrote in the comments, the question can be answered by the following code

```
A[\[Psi]] = 1;
B[\[Psi]] = 2;
A[\[Phi]] = 3;
B[\[Phi]] = 4;
A[\[Zeta]] = 3;
B[\[Zeta]] = 4;

list1 = {A, B};
list2 = {10*\[Psi], 5 \[Phi] + \[Zeta]};

list3 = Table[Table[i[First@Variables[j]], {i, list1}], {j, list2}]
```

which gives as the output the desired answer

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```